# Paramiko: Verifying and permanently adding SSH host key

Tags: ssh-keys, paramiko

With Paramiko, one can set up a SSH key callback like this:

```
def someCallbackFunction(client, hostname, key):
    ...

client = SSHClient()

client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(someCallbackFunction) # <--
client.connect(...)
```

The callback gets the SSH client instance, the hostname and a [`paramiko.RSAKey`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.RSAKey-class.html) instance as parameters and must return if the key is accepted, or raise an exception otherwise.

How can I verify the SSH key with the provided parameters? For example, how can I get the RSA fingerprint so that the user can compare it? And is it possible to let Paramiko permanently add the key to "known_hosts"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to write to (Open)SSH's known_hosts file, but as there are different variants (as of the PuTTY source code), I will just leave this and write accepted hosts to my own program's configuration.

Concerning the fingerprint, I found that Paramiko already provides this: [`PKey.get_fingerprint`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.PKey-class.html#get_fingerprint). In order to get the human-readable fingerprint, simply apply `binascii.hexlify`.